# What is the etiquette on moving a Question from another site to this one?

Tags: discussion

I posted a Question on the Linguistics site https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14848/where-to-find-old-article-on-frequency-of-letters-pairs-of-letters-triplets-an

I have a partial answer covering the more technical part of the Question.  In a few days, if I don't get the rest of the info I want, I would like to Accept the Linguistics Answer and repost the Question on this site, along with the information (properly credited) that I have gained from Linguistics.

Other than Commenting on Linguistics that I am going to do this, it there anything else I should do?

Comment: i wouldn't recommend doing that. The question looks better suited to Linguistics SE than English Language and Usage SE to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that your question is sufficiently different from the one on Linguistics (just reposting *the same question* on different sites is against overall SE policy) and that your question is on-topic for this site (which I believe means it should be about English in particular rather than about an issue that is the same no matter what language we're looking at). Honestly, I'm not sure that it would be on-topic, so as I said in the comments, I'd advise against doing this.